# How to create a class and store it instead of just creating it

Tags: c++

I have a `Window` and a `Renderer` class. The following is how I instantiated these classes.

```
class SDL_UI
    {
    private:
        Window window;
        Renderer renderer;
        Event event;

    public:
        SDL_UI(const char* name, int sw, int sh)
        {
            init();
            window = Window(name, sw, sh);
            renderer = Renderer(window);
            while (true)
            {
                if (event.handleEvents()) SDL_Quit();
            }
        }
    };
```

This causes all sorts of problems such as window closing as soon as it's created, and issues with renderer as well. I am assuming that the way I am trying to store them is not the proper way? But than again the compiler didn't give any warnings in visual studio.

Now, if I don't store these classes in a variable and do the following, it works fine.

```
class SDL_UI
    {
    public:
        SDL_UI(const char* name, int sw, int sh)
        {
            init();
            Event event;
            Window window (name, sw, sh);
            Renderer renderer(window);
            while (true)
            {
                if (event.handleEvents()) SDL_Quit();
            }
        }
    };
```

But I need to access these classes from outside the constructor. I was considering making them public so possibly from outside the class as well. How would I do this?

Here are the window and renderer classes in case they are important to the problem.

```
class Window
    {
    private:
        SDL_Window* window = nullptr;
        
    public:
        Window() {};
        Window(const char* name, int sw, int sh, bool fullScreen = false)
        {
            window = SDL_CreateWindow(name, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, sw, sh, fullScreen);
            if (window == nullptr)
            {
                std::stringstream buffer;
                if (debug)
                    std::cout << buffer.str() << std::endl;
                buffer << "Window creation error: " << SDL_GetError();
            }
        }

        ~Window() { SDL_DestroyWindow( window ); }

        operator SDL_Window* () { return window; };
    };

    class Renderer
    {
    private:
        SDL_Renderer* renderer = nullptr;

    public:
        Renderer() {};
        Renderer(SDL_Window* window)
        {
            renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
            if (renderer == nullptr)
            {
                std::stringstream buffer;
                buffer << "Renderer creation Error: " << SDL_GetError();
                if (debug)
                    std::cout << buffer.str() << std::endl;
                throw std::runtime_error(buffer.str());
            }
        }
        
        ~Renderer() { SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer); }

        operator SDL_Renderer* () { return renderer; };
    };
```

Comment: With e.g. `window = Window(...)`, a copy is created which might cause your problems (I don't know why exactly). Why don't you just write `SDL_UI(...) : window(name, sw, sh)` etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would try is to use an *initializer list*

```
    SDL_UI(const char* name, int sw, int sh) : window(name, sw, sh), renderer(window)
    {
        init();
        while (true)
        {
            if (event.handleEvents()) SDL_Quit();
        }
    }
```

This avoids the default construction, copying and assignment of the window and renderer that your code is doing. Remember all (non-static) class members are constructed **before** you enter the body of your class constructor. If you want to control this process then an initializer list is the way to go.